# Constrain drag of movie clip to mask, with stage & mc scaling

Tags: actionscript-3

I'd like to constrain the drag of a movieclip to a mask called themapmask. The draggable mc's name is mapcontainer.themap. It's parent, mapcontainer, is scaled proportionately with the stage. How can i constrain the dragged mc to the mask? The code below works on load, but not when the stage is scaled.

```
function constrainMap():void {
    leftedge = themapmask.x+mapcontainer.themap.width/2-mapcontainer.x;
    rightedge= themapmask.x+themapmask.width-mapcontainer.width/2-mapcontainer.x;
    topedge = themapmask.y+mapcontainer.themap.height/2-mapcontainer.y;
    bottomedge = themapmask.y+themapmask.height-mapcontainer.height/2-mapcontainer.y;
    if (mapcontainer.themap.x>leftedge) mapcontainer.themap.x=leftedge;
    if (mapcontainer.themap.y>topedge) mapcontainer.themap.y=topedge;
    if (mapcontainer.themap.x<rightedge) mapcontainer.themap.x=rightedge;
    if (mapcontainer.themap.y<bottomedge) mapcontainer.themap.y=bottomedge;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Sprite.startDrag](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/Sprite.html) function accepts a second argument especially for drag area constraints, and the [DisplayObject.getBounds](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/DisplayObject.html) function returns a rectangle with the boundaries of the applied-to object within the context of the argument DisplayObject. So, basically, what you need to do is:

```
mapcontainer.themap.startDrag(false /*or true*/, themapmask.getBounds(mapcontainer));
```

and you can let go of the whole constrainMap function altogether.

Comment: That's not working - perhaps because the draggable clip has it's registration point at the center. Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah, so in that case, you need to make some changes to the rectangle you send to startDrag, something like:

Comment: @user1342133 `var rect:Rectangle = themapmask.getBounds(mapcontainer); mapcontainer.themap.startDrag(false /*or true*/, new Rectangle(rect.left + mapcontainer.themap.width / 2, rect.top + mapcontainer.themap.height / 2, rect.width - mapcontainer.themap.width, rect.height - mapcontainer.themap.height))`